# rails : How can I call methods in the nested model from parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my model.

Survey

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:content].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
```

Question : there is is_correct(boolean) column which indicates whether students get the right answer or not.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Answer : there is correct(boolean) column which teacher checks making the survey(test), and there is user_answer(boolean) column which students mark taking the test.

```
class Answer < ActviveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
```

I want to compare correct and user_answer in Answer model, and save the answer to is_correct in Question model.

There are not only basic CRUD methods for generating question and answer, but also three extra methods for answering(GET)/grading(POST) examination, showing(GET) results. I can check there are no problem in this routes from the result of rake routes.

**Updated Question : I changed my controller and Question model.**

Here are methods in survey controller.

```
def answering
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end

def grading
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.user_id = current_user.id
  @survey.questions.each do |q|
    q.auto_check 
  end 
  redirect_to results_survey_path(@survey)
end

def results
end
```

Here is question controller.

```
def auto_check
  answers.each do |a|
    is_correct = true if a.user_answer and a.correct 
    self.save!
  end
end
```

The result of rake routes.

```
$ rake routes | grep survey
(in /home/seriousin/ClassCasts)
        answering_survey GET    /surveys/:id/answering(.:format)            surveys#answering
          grading_survey POST   /surveys/:id/grading(.:format)              surveys#grading
          results_survey GET    /surveys/:id/results(.:format)              surveys#results
                 surveys GET    /surveys(.:format)                          surveys#index
                         POST   /surveys(.:format)                          surveys#create
              new_survey GET    /surveys/new(.:format)                      surveys#new
             edit_survey GET    /surveys/:id/edit(.:format)                 surveys#edit
                  survey GET    /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#show
                         PUT    /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#update
                         DELETE /surveys/:id(.:format)                      surveys#destroy
```

**The problem is I can't call survey object saved user input. **

I let the results method empty. Using redirect_to, I don't need to generate another survey object.

```
  def results
      #@survey = Survey.where(params[:survey_id])
  end
```

I think it's OK. Because I can pass survey object as a parameter from grading method.

```
def grading
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.user_id = current_user.id
  @survey.questions.each do |q|
    q.auto_check 
  end 
  redirect_to results_survey_path(@survey)
end
```

But the result is 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'... How can I use object contains user input?

Thanks advanced.

Comment: 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass'... Where are u getting this error? Please post the full trace and i couldn't few parts of your question. Please make everything clear.

Comment: The error 'undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass' generally means that you are calling name method on a nil object. Check that.

Comment: I changed redirect_to to '    render (:action => 'results', :object => @survey)' and I can get it!

Answer (score 0):

`auto_check` method should be inside the question model, not inside the Question Controller.

Comment: It doesn't work! OMG

irb(main):001:0> Question.first.auto_check
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `auto_check' for #<Question:0x7f5916f87ed0>
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>

Comment: That's it. The auto_check hasto be in question model, not in question controller.

Comment: Thank you Charizard. You got the point and I can deal with that process in the question model. But I still have a problem. I updated my question. Please help me one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@survey.questions.each` gives you an instance of Question model and you are calling a method defined in the `QuestionsController` on it.  Had the `auto_check` been a member of `Question` model you wouldn't have received this error.

If you want to keep `auto_check` method in the `QuestionsController` then I think you should pass in the `question` instance as a parameter like follows:

```
def auto_check(question)
  question.answers.each do |a|
    is_correct = true if a.user_answer and a.correct 
    ...
  end
end
```

and update the call as follows:

```
@survey.questions.each do |q|
  auto_check(q)
end
```

Comment: I think putting the business logic inside the controller is a bad practice. It will be better to put the auto_check methos inside the question model.

Comment: @Charizard_, absolutely agree.  I guess my answer doesn't directly imply that does it, the last line of first paragraph and first line of second paragraph.  Thanks for the comment though, at least it's recorded.

Comment: Thank you vinodadhikary! I can solve this problem.(I wrote it in the question model.) But I have still problem. I updated my question. please check.

Comment: @user2681054, Please post your full trace.

Comment: Thank you for your concerning. I solved this problem using this line.  ' render (:action => 'results', :object => @survey)' instead of redirect_to