# Rails 3 : How can I put boolean data from check_box_tag in nested_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Actually I tried to this with radio_button, but I gave up.(Too much complicated for me.)

I have DB tables 'question', 'answer'.(Those two tables has been related by has_many and belongs_to, and nested_form relationship.)

And there is user_answer(boolean, created by default value 'false') column in answer table.

I want to make it like this.

1. If user check the check_box, user_answer change to 'true' value.
2. Then I'll compare another value in correct column in answer table,
3. and finally I'll save the result in is_correct column in question table.

But I don't know how can I do. This is input form.

```
<h1><%= @survey.name %></h1>
 <%= form_tag({:controller => "surveys", :action => "grading"}) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
   <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
   <li>
   <strong><%= question.content %></strong>
    <ol class="checkbox">
     <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
       <%= check_box_tag(answer.user_answer) %>
       <%= label answer.content) %>
     <% end %>
     </ol>
     <hr />
   </li>
   <% end %>
  </ol>

  <div><%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "submit") %></div>
```

But answer.user_answer is always 'false', it's not changed at all. How can I change this line?

```
  <%= check_box_tag(answer.user_answer) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
 <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'answers[]', answer %>
   <%= label answer.content %>
 <% end %>
```

will send `params[:answers]` to your controller. Do all of your comparisons, etc. in your controller.

Comment: Oops, wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) error has been occurred!

Comment: You'll have to modify the controller code to work with the change

Comment: Still not changed. I already have written grading function in other controller and other model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267663/rails-how-can-i-call-methods-in-the-nested-model-from-parents The only thing I need to do is just changing true value in user_answer field in answers tables when I checked it.